# Does the web-based Evernote app have keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, evernote

If it does? What are they?

The most important shortcuts for me are: search & new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note that **some limited keyboard shortcuts**/hotkeys work with the current version (Feb 2017).

The ones I have found are:

- **bold** `ctrl-b`
- *italics* `ctrl-i`

I've searched for an official list, but there doesn't appear to be one. This could be because different browsers and platforms may have  conflicting shortcuts.

Eg:
In the list of keyboard shortcuts for [Evernote for Windows](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/209004807-What-are-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-Evernote-for-Windows-) `ctrl-e` centres text, but in Chrome browser it will shift focus to the search bar.

Answer (score 6):

There is a Chrome extension that offers this functionality;

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hffokedddmbcngcmkhpbdoeljdglfpna?hl=en

> ... add gmail like keyboard shortcuts to Evernote ...

Hope this helps

Comment: It has a rating of 1.6 stars out of 5 - so not really a good solution at this time.

Comment: "Not work for me" is the most comments there.:(

Answer (score 1):

None of the extensions worked for me so I wrote my own called [Evercuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evercuts/hojeljpilmhieiaecibmdmdjhfijecgd). It's really pretty simple but it does most of what I need. (FYI its only available for chrome)

```
Search
Toggle Fullscreen
Move Note
Delete Note
Copy Note Internal Link
Open note in new tab
Open note in new window
Navigate the notes up/down
```

The above shortcuts are configurable via chrome://extensions/shortcuts

You can also Alt+Click on a note to open it fullscreen in a new window.

The code is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/RealP/evercuts) or you can install directly from the [Chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evercuts/hojeljpilmhieiaecibmdmdjhfijecgd).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good chrome extension [Evernote Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-shortcuts/clhjalfedcigiomjfmmjhgadnlmegobb?hl=en)

**Few shortcuts which it offers:**

```
General options:
    ?      show the help dialog
    A      Add a note
    /      search notes
    W      goto Workchat
    S      goto Shortcuts
    N      goto Notes
    B      goto noteBooks
    T      goto Tags
    C      goto Contiguration

Dialogs:
    Enter  accept
    Esc    cancel

Nodes list:
    j      next note
    k      previous note
    l      edit note
    oc     Order by Creation date (newest first)
    oC     Order by Creation date (oldest first)
    ou     Order by Updated date (newest first)
    oU     Order by Updated date (oldest first)
    ot     Order by Title (ascending)
    oT     Order by Title (descending)
    vi     Toggle view text
    vt     Toggle view images

Note:
    c      change note Caption
    s      Star note
    i      note Info
    d      Delete note
    r      Reminder for note
    b      move note to noteBook
    t      Tag note
    F      Focus toggle

Note Sharing:
    hs     Send note
    hf     Facebook
    ht     Twitter
    hi     LinkedIn
    he     Email
    hl     Link

Notebook list:
    j      next notebook
    k      previous notebook
    Enter  select notebook
    l      select notebook
    d      delete notebook
    e      email notebook
    s      Star notebook
    a      Add Notebook
    f      Enter search Field
    x      Clear search notebook

Search window:
    w      change Where to search
    a      Add search to saved
    f      enter search Field
    x      Clear search field

Miscelaneous:
    Esc    exit field
    a      create tag/chat
    f      enter search Field
    x      clear search field

Configuration Menu:
    s      Settings
    h      Help & Learning
    r      Rate Evernote Web
    l      Log out

Note editing:
    Esc             Exit note editor
    Ctrl+z          Undo
    Ctrl+Shift+z    Redo
    ⇄               Indent
    Shift+⇄         Unindent
    Ctrl+b          Bold
    Ctrl+i          Italic
    Ctrl+u          Underline
    Ctrl+Alt+a      Attach file
    Ctrl+Alt+b      Bulleted list
    Ctrl+Alt+c      Checkbox
    Ctrl+Alt+d      Divider line
    Ctrl+Alt+e      Align center
    Ctrl+Alt+k      Insert link
    Ctrl+Alt+l      Align left
    Ctrl+Alt+n      Numbered list
    Ctrl+Alt+p      Code block
    Ctrl+Alt+r      Align right
    Ctrl+Alt+s      Strikethrough
    Ctrl+Alt+x      Remove formatting
    Ctrl+Alt+=      Subscript
    Ctrl+Alt++      Superscript
```